# Windows 2019 php 7.4 cannot connect to 2016 SQL Server

Tags: php, sql-server, database, windows, server

I have a new windows 2019 server running IIS with PHP 7.4.x and is working properly and the sql server and odbc drivers were installed.

Now when I try to connect to a remote mssql instance , I get the following error.

```
$serverName = "//servername\dbinstance";
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"DBname", "UID"=>"username", "PWD"=>"password");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);
if( $conn ) {
     echo "Connection established.<br />";
}else{
     echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
```

I installed SSMS on the php server and I can connect to the remote database server without any problems!

What did I do wrong with php?

In linux, it may fail because of SELinux turned on but this is Windows 2019 LOL

thoughts?

thanks

Comment: Can you post the actual error message?

Comment: Can you see the connection attempt in the SAL Server logs? If so, what is the connecy error logged there as well? If not, then the connection details aren't reaching it and therefore are likely wrong.

Comment: I'm not that familiar with SQL server. Is your database instance literally called `dbinstance` or something else that starts with `n`, `r`, `t` or [some other character](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double) that is transformed into something else when combined with a single backslash? Can you connect if you escape the backslash (`"//servername\\dbinstance"`)?

Comment: Could not connect. Array ([0] => Array([0] => 08001[SQLSTATE] => 08001[1] => 161[code] => 161[2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [161].[message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [161].)[1] => Array([0] => HYT00[SQLSTATE] => HYT00[1] => 0[code] => 0[2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired[message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired)[2] =>...

Comment: .r]Login timeout expired)[2] => Array([0] => 08001[SQLSTATE] => 08001[1] => 161[code] => 161[2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.[message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server.

Comment: Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.) )

Comment: dbinstance is just an example... ours is ourserver.example.com\dbsql

Comment: escaping the slash before the instance name did not work... same error... is there something in the IIS that maybe too "secure" now Could not connect. Array ([0] => Array([0] => 08001[SQLSTATE] => 08001[1] => -1[code] => -1[2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]SQL Server Network Interfaces: Error Locating Server/Instance Specified [xFFFFFFFF].[message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]SQL Server Network Interfaces: Error Locating Server/Instance Specified [xFFFFFFFF].) shows the error as

Comment: sqlsrv
sqlsrv support

enabled

ExtensionVer  5.8.0+12928

Comment: What is a SAL log?

Comment: I can telnet to it no problem... so it looks like php in my windows server is the problem... is there a setting I am missing?

Comment: firewall is turned off as well and ports tcp 1433 is listening ...

Comment: I figured it out... weird,,, you don't need the instance name and just use the server name

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out... weird,,, you don't need the instance name and just use the server name